# Sending a list's values through a function

Tags: python, interpreter

I'm creating a simple interpreter for a programming language I made. I'm trying to make it so you can put multiple statements on one line. (Like `print "Hello"; print "World"`. The statements are separated using a semicolon `;`)

The problem is, I'm getting an error when I try to use multiple statements in the interpreter.

What I'm doing is taking the user input, and splitting it at a semicolon (the pieces go into a list). I want the list's values to run through the `parse()` function that I have.

**In short, I want to run a list's values through a function.**

Here's my current code:

```
if ';' in command:
        semiCount = command.count(';')
        command.split(';')
        for i in range(0, semiCount):
            command[i].replace(" ", "")
            parse(command[i])
```

Comment: Note: `command[i].replace(" ", "")` does nothing because you didn't assign the result. `str` is immutable; the original string is not changed when you call `replace` on it. `str.replace` returns a new `str`, but you didn't assign it anywhere (either to `command[i]` or passing it to `parse` or assigning to some other name), so the result is immediately discarded. Same goes for `command.split(';')`; it returns a new `list` which you immediately discard, when you probably should have reassigned `command` or stored to a new name (or just iterated the result directly).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time I work with lists :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand, you want this:

```
temp_input=raw_input()  #taking the input
lst=temp_input.split(";") # splitting the input and saving in a list
for i in lst: # iterating through the list
    parse(i) # calling parse() with single list element
```

Is it what you want?